# I cant seen to use ToList(); or take(6) items on this select statement

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-entities

I cant seen to use ToList(); or take(6) items on this select statement.
I need to select only 6. this is what i have witch works but displays 1 only on the 6 iterations of the repeater.

```
    public string GetImage(string pId)
    {
        Compras context = new Compras();
        Product pr = context.Products.FirstOrDefault();
        if (pr != null && pr.Picture != null && pr.Picture.Count() > 0)
        {
            return "data:image/jpg;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String((pr.Picture));
        }
        return "data:image/jpg;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(File.ReadAllBytes(Server.MapPath("~/") + "white.jpg"));
    }
```

I wish i could use as on this next:

```
        var context = new Compras();
        var prouctQ = from p in context.Products.Take(6) select new { p.ProductName, p.Picture }; //with projections
        var Products = prouctQ.ToList();
        if (Products.Count > 0)
```

Comment: And what happens when you do that?

Comment: I have a asp:Repeater wired to a statement that selects 6, then binary image that with that code shows the same image on the 6 products because i'm doing .FirstOrDefault(); i cant' to be able to use take or tolist there because of the rest of the code. thanks

Comment: Sorry, that really isn't very clear at all. Are you saying that you *can* use `Take` and `ToList`, it's just that you don't know what you need to do with the list afterwards?

Comment: I don't see any call to GetImage(string pId) method.Also the two codes are disconnected. The first set of code shows the same image coz it is always the first element. The second set shows you are selecting 6 elements.what are you intended to do?

Comment: yes and thank you nikita. I wish i could use the second code(where i take 6) but i having been able to use it because the variable pr . see the if on first code? if (pr != null && pr.Picture != null && pr.Picture.Count() > 0)

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that you have "using System.Linq" at the top of the code file.

Comment: Use `using System.Linq` is an answer, but  `Please make sure that you have "using System.Linq"` implies *"try it and return me the response"*. which is more like a comment than answer. http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment

Comment: yes i have it. is the select statement that selects only 1 image. thanks